# Как удалить определённые строки из файла, используя combobox для выбора

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Как удалить определённые строки из файла, используя combobox для выбора (например человека и нескольких его параметров).
Есть 2 файла, в одном логины и пароли, в другом полностью все данные(включая логины и пароли), к примеру пути:
@"D:\Win\LP-A.txt"
@"D:\Win\Users\тут поиск по логинам сделать.txt"

Вот примерный алгоритм:

открыть исходный файл на чтение
открыть временный файл на запись.
счетчик строк = 0
пока (есть строки в исходном файле) (while (not in.eof()))
  прочитать строку
  увеличить счетчик строк на 1
  если счетчик строк равен заданной строке, то пропустить (continue)
  записать прочитанную строку в временный файл.
конец_цикла
закрыть исходный файл
закрыть временный файл
Удалить исходный файл
переместить временный файл на место исходного файла.

Comment: Что-то слишком похоже на "сделайте все за меня"

Answer (score 0):

Ну все же просто!
 1. открыть исходный файл на чтение
 2. открыть временный файл на запись
 3. счетчик строк = 0
 4. Пока не кончится файл
    4.1 прочитать строку
    4.2 увеличить счетчик строк на 1
    4.3 если счетчик строк равен заданной строке, то пропустить (continue)
    4.4  записать прочитанную строку в временный файл
 5. закрыть исходный файл
 6. закрыть временный файл
 7. Удалить исходный файл
 8. Переместить временный файл на место исходного файла